# About printer name

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a printer installed and sharing on a server, which is having a meaningful naming
[image: Printer]

When I right click the printer and connect it then go to Device and Printers, it becomes the printer model instead of my previous naming
[image]

I go to the printer property, it is not allowing me to rename it
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this problem specific to a particular computer and a particular printer ?

Comment: No, actually this is a print server contain multiple printers for our colleague to connect and use it. I don't think the naming is the big issue until one day my boss ask me which is the pantry printer, why the naming is like this.....

Comment: You mean every computer shows the printer with the model not by name

Comment: Yes, when I browser it from \\printserver, I can see my custom name, but when I connect it, it becomes the model name

Comment: **You mean every computer shows the printer with the model not by name** ?????? **Or is it just one computer???**

Comment: every computers